# Get image from URL programmatically from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, url

I need to get an image by a url that i create from a couple of fields in my MySQL database.
So, i get two fields: 'id' & 'placeID' and I do this command:

```
select concat('http://whatever.come?id=',
              cast(Votis.SequencialDoCandidato as char),
              '&placeID=',
              cast(IDUnidadeEleitoral as char))
from database.table;
```

This URL points to a picture.

So my questions is: 'Is there anyway of insert automatically the picture that this URL brings into a image field?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible and would be a really horrible mix anyway as it's not your database's job to retrieve an URL.

Comment: I will say, use PHP or a other server language for in step 1 copy the image from the target URL to you server, and then insert the image to you database as step 2.